# Topology: Continuity of functions

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Lately I've been dusting up my topological skills, after some negligence (and due to too much time), and I've stumbled upon my old course notes, with such a question:
Check wheter or not given transformations are continuous:

1. $T(f):(C[0,1],d_{sup})\to (\mathbb{R},d_E)$ given as $T(f)= f(const), const\in [0,1]$
2. $T(f):(C[0,1],d_{sup})\to(C[0,1],d_{sup})$ given as $T(f)=2f(1-x)-3$
3. $T(f):(C^1[0,1],d_{sup})\to(C[0,1],d_{sup})$ given as $T(f)=f'(x)$

Now the 2nd. one seems easy to me, as we can easily see that $T$ is nothing more than a composition of continuous functions, and as such we can easily write any continuous function as the composition of a shift by 3, scaling by 2 and taking $1-x$ doesn't affect $sup$ over x, so the inverse image of $B(f,\epsilon)$ will also be $B(\frac{f+3}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

But I am kind of stuck with 1st and 3rd.

In the first case, I am quite sure that this will be suriection, but I can't wrap my mind whether or not would it be continuous, as the set $\{f\in C[0,1]:f(const)\in B_E(x,e)\}=\{f\in C[0,1]:|f(const)-x|<e\}$ definitely has an open subset (Open ball around constant function x with radius e), and seems like a sum of open sets, but I don't see whether or not is it open.

As far as 3rd. goes, I only know that $C^1[0,1]$ is a subset of $C[0,1]$ and the set of nowhere differentiable functions is dense in $C[0,1]$, but my intuition tells me that we can always try to approximate a nondifferentiable function by a differentiable one, and... I don't know how to bite this one.

Any hint or help, or even answer as I am just curious will be a welcome one :)

Comment: I don't understand the second function. What is that $g$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry for misleading; pushed a wrong button on the keyboard. Now it should be fine, so in that case not $g$ but $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is continuous. Fix $x_0\in[0,1]$ and let $T(f)=f(x_0)$. If $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and then\begin{align}d_\sup(f_,f_2)<\delta&\iff d_\sup(f_,f_2)<\varepsilon\\&\iff\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|<\varepsilon\\&\implies|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x)_|<\varepsilon.\end{align}

The third one is discontinuous. If $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}n$, then you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}T(f_n)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for great answer and explanation!